# How to run 2 files c# without opening window

Tags: c#

I got 1 mapper (.exe) and 1 driver (.sys) and i want to do so that when i execute them i want to run mapper as admin with the driver and not create a window (keep it hidden). can anyone help. I have the following code down but nor does it run the mapper as admin with the spoof and it still also creates a window! help!

````
            string map = "C:\\SCSpoofer\\mapper.exe";

            Process myProcess = new Process();
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            myProcess = Process.Start(map, sys);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
            myProcess.Kill();```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a Process to launch a command window (hidden) to create the item templates
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Project.ServicesFolder;
startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + CreateServices;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

This is from my open source project DataTier.Net github.com/DataJuggler/DataTier.Net

Comment: but how can i run this with 2 files